# Show app as "Import with <AppName>" in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, ios-extensions, ios-sharesheet

I'm implementing export / import feature for my app:

Export data with custom file extension (Backup.appname) → tap on file in mail or iCloud drive → have my app shown as "Import with AppName" in share sheet.

I added a custom UTI and document type to my app's plist as [explained here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html). Everything works as it should, **except** my app is shown as "Copy to AppName", and not "Import with AppName".

How can I get it shown as "Import with AppName"? I've seen other apps have it for their custom file types.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to override activityTitle?
override func activityTitle() -> String? {
    return "Import with AppName" //The string you return should be localized.
}

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan isn't that's for activities done while in app? My question is for when you are in a different app – Mail, iCloud Drive, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It happens because you are using key `LSHandlerRank` with value `Owner`. If you change this value to `Alternate`, text will change to `Import with <AppName>`.

I can't find any documented confirmation about this behavior ([only possible types of handler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html)), as well as what will happen if you change the value of `LSHandlerRank` for your custom type.

Seems that most of apps use common types, such as `public.data`, `public.content` and don't set value of `LSHandlerRank` at all.